# How to check statistics on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, statistics

How can we check statistics on Stack Overflow?

Statistics for:

- questions with highest votes
- questions which weren't answered
- questions on a certain date

All these are like statistics around questions raised in Stack Overflow.

Can every one see them or does it depend upon a permission-based view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions sorted by votes are available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

Questions without an answer are available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered

Questions asked on a certain date are available at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2014-08-20 (see [Add date range to "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55037/add-date-range-to-advanced-super-ninja-search-options))

Other statistics may be available with search filters or in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)